# Help me solve this exponentiation riddle

Tags: exponentiation, puzzle

Some friend showed me the following calculation that leads to an obviously wrong conclusion, but I can't find where it goes wrong:
For $k\in \mathbb{R}\\
e^{\pi ik}=e^{\pi i \frac{k}{2}\times 2} =(e^{2\pi i})^{\frac{k}{2}}=1^{\frac{k}{2}}=1$

Which step is illegal?

Comment: The second step is wrong because all the other steps are correct.

Comment: $1^{1/2}=\pm 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\frac{k}{2}$ is a non-integer rational, then $z^{k/2}$ is a multi-valued function, and which value is meant here is ambiguous at best. If $\frac{k}{2}$ is irrational, the formula $(e^{2\pi i})^{k/2}$ doesn't even have a clearly defined meaning.

Comment: I know that in complex analysis, the log function and roots have that problem because of the problem when z=0. But where does that problem appear in exponential functions?

Comment: There are actually a few different functions we call $x^y$. If $y$ is an integer, $x$ can be any complex number (really, any element of any multiplicative group), except $x=0$ and $y\leq 0$. If $x$ is a positive real number, $y$ can be any complex number, and $x^y = \exp(y \ln x)$. Both these definitions guarantee $a^{bc} = (a^b)^c$. If $y$ is a non-integer rational $y=\frac{p}{q}$, then we have a multi-valued function with $q$ different solutions when $x \neq 0$. Otherwise the meaning is unclear....

Comment: ... Sometimes in complex numbers, $x^y$ is taken to mean $x^y = \exp(y \ln x)$ using the principle branch of $\ln$. But that branch causes issues such as making $a^{bc} = (a^b)^c$ sometimes false (like in this incorrect calculation).

Comment: The log function $w=\ln z$ and roots (rational powers) $w = z^{1/n}$ have multi-values or branch cuts because there are multiple solutions to $\exp(w) = z$ and $w^n=z$. That doesn't have much to do with $z=0$.

Answer (score 1):

When $k=1$, this gives the traditional wrong string $(-1)^1=(-1)^{1/2\times2}=((-1)^2)^{1/2}=1^{1/2}=1$, and fails in general for the same reason it fails in particular.